# Error al generar apk

Tags: android, gradle

Tengo un error al general mi apk, mi gradle es el siguiente:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.taxiconductor"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

> 23:32:25 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 23:37:11 Gradle build
>   finished with 1 error(s) in 4m 44s 524ms 23:37:12 Build APK: Errors
>   while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.
>   23:57:23 Gradle sync started

```
> Error:Execution failed for task
> ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. >
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
> 0xffff]: 65536
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: Y cual es el mensaje que se muestra en el apartado "Messages", o en el Log?

Comment: Ese, sorry pero estaba editando

Comment: Esta pregunta ya se realizo te recomiendo buscar primeramente tu pregunta en el sitio. @CarlosHernández

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata de agregar la siguiente dependencia dentro de el archivo gradle de tu app.

```
 com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0
```

y dentro del bloque defaultConfig habilita el soporte a multiDex con esto

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

La información en este enlace tal vez te ayude a complementar la respuesta.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=es-419

Comment: Genial me sirvió, gracias amigo